# Consequences of canvas resizing

Tags: javascript, canvas

So I'm trying to optimize my code by only accessing the DOM's canvas properties when the window is resized but I'm getting this weird problem. Why does the resizing prevent this? P.S. not sure what to include I have 2k lines of code right now.

I'm using

```
document.getElementById('mycanvas').getContext("2d").clearRect(-2000, -2000, 2000, 2000)
```

With this in my render loop:

```
document.getElementById('mycanvas').getContext("2d").height = window.innerHeight
```

[image]

Without it:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting either `width` or `height` properties of your HTMLCanvasElement will reset **all** the properties of your context to their default. It will also remove all clipping areas, and more interestingly in your case, it will reset the transformation matrix, and set a new pixel data (all transparent-black). And this is slow, so you are right removing it from your code.

Your call to `ctx.clearRect` sets the `x` and `y` coords to `-2000`, this means that with a default matrix transform, you are clearing non-existing pixels.
Setting your HTMLCanvasElement.height was what cleared your canvas previously.

We can also see on your second screenshot that you are drawing the grid slightly more on the bottom-right every time, this indicates that you are probably modifying the context matrix (e.g `ctx.translate(x, y)`).
Now that you don't reset it with the `height` setting, you need to do it explicitly. This can be done with [`ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setTransform).

So a basic start for a drawing function would look like

```
function draw() {
  // clear
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // reset the transform matrix (fast)
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // clear all pixels (fast)
  //... start drawing ...
```

Now, there might be other properties that you assumed where reset to their defaults while they're not, e.g `fillStyle` etc. Most of them can be simply set to what you want when needed.
If you are using `ctx.clip()` however (but looking at the screenshot, it seems you're not), you'd need to [save()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save) and [restore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/restore) the context's state to be able to remove the clipping area (bad API design...).

Comment: I tried that and it kind of worked but it's not clearing the screen and just rendering on top of itself. Do I need to add translate(0,0) or something too?

Comment: You need to show your code. But thos will clear your canvas, except if you did clip() it.

Comment: I don't clip it, all I do to the canvas itself is translate it, rotate it and render things outside the specified pixel margin, my FPS function now reads 0  and I think it's rendering all the images on top of each other ... should I share it in a JS fiddle or something?

Comment: sorry @Kaiido not sure if I tagged you

Comment: thanks for your help! I figured out that it was because I wasn't closing my drawing of the grid

Comment: Yes, always start a path declaration with ctx.beginPath. (Beware though ctx.closePath doesn't close the path declaration, it's a lineTo last point we did moveTo

Comment: oh @kaiido is there a better way to do this then? or a way to clean it up?

Comment: Yes, `ctx.beginPath()`

Comment: but still use ctx.closePath()? or just ignore that?

Comment: Yes just ignore ctx.closePath, you don't need it here.

Comment: okay thanks so much again, one question while I have you ... would it be more efficient to just put my js variables directly into the CSS?